# How to delete contents of an Excel sheet in Java?

Tags: java, excel, excel-2003, apache-poi

How to delete contents of an Excel sheet in an Excel workbook, using Java SE and Apache POI?

Comment: you want to delete everything in the workbook?

Comment: Nope, just all the contents of the current HSSFSheet

Comment: @ShumonSaha have you got the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 6):

I've found that removeSheetAt/createSheet isn't really an acceptable answer, because you can't put the new sheet into the correct position in the workbook without running into a bug in [WorkSheet.setSheetOrder](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50083)

This code snippet

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
   sheet.removeRow(row);
}
```

in my world throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`

I had to resort to

```
    for (int index = crnt.getLastRowNum(); index >= crnt.getFirstRowNum(); index--) {
        crnt.removeRow( crnt.getRow(index));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in previous comments

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
   sheet.removeRow(row);
}
```

this code throwing ConcurrentModificationException to me. So, I have modified the code and it's working fine. Here is the code:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIte =  sheet.iterator();
while(rowIte.hasNext()){
    rowIte.next();              
    rowIte.remove();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with version 4.0.0, however VoiceOfUnreason's code did.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on *what* contents you want to delete you may remove a single cell or row.

Too erase the complete sheet [iterate](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) over all rows and delete it.

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
   sheet.removeRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you first delete the complete sheet using jkraybill's answer   and then add an empty sheet. It think it would be cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I think I found the best solution

What I did was just create a new workbook of the same type and save it over the file that I wanted to delete.

Heres the code

```
private void clearOldFile(){
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try{
        oldFile = new XSSFWorkbook();    
        Sheet sheet = oldFile.createSheet("temp data");

        out = new FileOutputStream(AbsolutePathForTempExcelFile);
        oldFile.write(out);
        out.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution delete all of the sheets in the workbook, not just the active one? The original question asked about just the active sheet.

Comment: Then all you have to do is create a for loop that copies all but page index 0. Thats very easy to do. Just use int sheetNum = oldFile.getNumberOfSheets(); then use all of the indexes except 0.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `HSSFWorkbook.removeSheetAt(index)`.

Comment: Nope, I want to keep the sheet but without any data

Comment: Please clarify your original question then. Are you trying to erase the data in every cell but preserve the formatting etc?

Comment: I'm trying to erase data+formatting in every cell, as if the sheet has just been created

Comment: Hey jkraybill, if you add `HSSFWorkbook.createSheet()`, than your answer will fit to Sumon's needs =D

Comment: For me removing a sheet at a given index occasionally throws a weird out of bounds exception, even though the sheet exists at that number. (POI 3.10) So clearing a sheet instead of re-creating it is imo the better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is an old thread but I also get ConcurrentModificationException. Based on VoiceOfUnreason I found this to work:

```
        while (xlsSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {
          xlsSheet.removeRow(xlsSheet.getRow(xlsSheet.getLastRowNum()));
        }
        if (xlsSheet.getDrawingPatriarch() != null) {
          xlsSheet.getDrawingPatriarch().clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got concurrent modification exception, also using the more "modern" way of doing it :

```
sheet.forEach(r->sheet.remove(r));
```

The iterator based solution from @Thirupathi S apparently worked, but for reasons I don't exactly know it was creating xslx files that were not readable by Apple's Numbers and OSX preview (and probably other softwares too).

I suspect this has something to do with the iterator not removing something: the code of the removeRow method is way more complex than the simple iterator remove operation.

Using old plain for-loop with reversed index worked like a charm :

```
for (int i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i >= 0; i--) {
  sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));
}
```

Comment: Throws null pointer exception if a row does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine with me. And also consider special cases, e.g. the sheet is blank, or the spaces between the firstRow and lastRow are present.

```
public void cleanSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    int numberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    if(numberOfRows > 0) {
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            if(sheet.getRow(i) != null) {
                sheet.removeRow( sheet.getRow(i));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Info: clean sheet='" + sheet.getSheetName() + "' ... skip line: " + i);
            }
        }               
    } else {
        System.out.println("Info: clean sheet='" + sheet.getSheetName() + "' ... is empty");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My reason for not deleting and recreating sheet: Keep references to sheet-scoped names working.

```
for(int i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i >= 0; i--)
{
  Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
  if(row != null)
  {
    sheet.removeRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other iterator methods appeared to work but Excel then refused to open the file.
This one worked for me:

```
int rownum;
while ((rownum=sheet.getLastRowNum()) > 0) sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(rownum));
```

Comment: This will not clean the first row (index 0) and throw null pointers if a row does not exist.